# shading under geom_step with discrete x-axis, respecting the factor order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to shade the area under a `geom_step()` curve on a plot with a discrete and ordered x-axis, e.g. to show the cumulative distribution for some frequency-ordered categories/

The basic `geom_step()` curve could be created like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

diamonds %>%
  group_by(color) %>%
  summarize(count=n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(count)) %>%
  mutate(frac_of_tot = count/sum(count),
         ecdf=cumsum(frac_of_tot),
         color=fct_reorder(color, ecdf)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=color, y=ecdf, group=0)) +
  geom_step() +
  expand_limits(y=0) +
  labs(title="a pareto-style cumulative distribution chart",
       subtitle="with x-axis ordered by decreasing frequency",
       y="cumulative fraction of total") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: a good geom_step chart]

but adding the shaded area using `geom_rect()` as taught by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70241211/1009730) seems to re-order the x-axis, resulting in a nonsensical plot:

```r
diamonds %>%
  group_by(color) %>%
  summarize(count=n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(count)) %>%
  mutate(frac_of_tot = count/sum(count),
         ecdf=cumsum(frac_of_tot),
         color=fct_reorder(color, ecdf)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=color, y=ecdf, group=0)) +
  geom_step() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=color, xmax=lead(color), ymin=0, ymax=ecdf), alpha=0.3) + 
  expand_limits(y=0) +
  labs(title="A sudden mess after adding geom_rect",
       subtitle="with x-axis surprisingly back in alpha order",
       y="cumulative fraction of total") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: an unordered mess]

Why is the `geom_rect()` layer causing the x-axis to be re-ordered?

How can I produce a plot that looks just like the first one, but with the area under the curve shaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that doing this with `geom_rect` is doing it the hard way. With some minor data reshaping you can simply use `geom_area`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(tidyr)

diamonds %>%
  group_by(color)        %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(count))   %>%
  mutate(frac_of_tot = count/sum(count),
         ecdf        = cumsum(frac_of_tot),
         ecd         = lag(ecdf),
         color       = fct_reorder(color, ecdf)) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("ecd")) %>%
  arrange(color, name) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = color, y = value, group = 0)) +
  geom_area(position = "identity", color = "black", alpha = 0.5) +
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  labs(title    = "a pareto-style cumulative distribution chart",
       subtitle = "with x-axis ordered by decreasing frequency",
       y        = "cumulative fraction of total") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]